# How to add client side validation to form via FAPI?

Tags: forms

I can't figure what to add Client Side Validation for form fields.

```
'#element_validate' => array('_file_generic_settings_max_filesize'),
```

I also don't know which value to put for different types of validation such as digit, email etc.
    '#element_validate' => 'email',

Also if I use this documentation https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#element_validate:

```
'#element_validate' => array('email'),
```

it states that it needs to be string not an array.

And after all this documentation doesn't state that how to add validation instead just creating own validation:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1324788

Comment: The Drupal FAPI doesn't provide clientside validation by default. You either need to add your own, or you need to find contributed modules that handle it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to add following for each integer field with form alter:

```
['#rules'] = array('digit');
```

And perhaps it was also needed to set 'views_exposed_filters' as a custom form for validation in the settings of Client Side Validation module.